# Typo3 Cache Flush Exception - How to debug

Tags: exception, typo3, typo3-console

I have a dockerized TYPO3 instance on a server and try to flush the typo3 cache manually.
So, I use the following command to do that, inside my docker container:

```
vendor/.bin/typo3cms cache:flush
```

However, it fails and returns this error:

```
[ TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception ]
Warning: rename(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/app/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 2432
```

How I can debug this and find out what the problem is?

Full stack trace with -vvv

```
  [ TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception ]
  Warning: rename(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/app/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utili
  ty/GeneralUtility.php line 2432


Exception code: 1

Exception trace:
#0 ()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Error/ErrorHandler.php:86
#1 Helhum\Typo3Console\Error\ErrorHandler->handleError()
#2 rename()
   typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php:2432
#3 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::flushDirectory()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Compatibility/TYPO3v87/Service/CacheLowLevelCleaner.php:31
#4 Helhum\Typo3Console\TYPO3v87\Service\CacheLowLevelCleaner->forceFlushCachesFiles()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Command/Cache/CacheFlushCommand.php:69
#5 Helhum\Typo3Console\Command\Cache\CacheFlushCommand->execute()
   vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
#6 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1000
#7 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/Symfony/Application.php:169
#8 Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\Symfony\Application->doRunCommand()
   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:271
#9 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:147
#10 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Core/Kernel.php:148
#11 Helhum\Typo3Console\Core\Kernel->handle()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:30
#12 {closure}()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:32
#13 require()
   vendor/helhum/typo3-console/typo3cms:3

cache:flush [--files-only]
```

Comment: Please retry with `-vvv` added which will give you a full stack trace. Then please update your question with that stack trace. Make sure to replace all file paths with dummy values.

Comment: @MathiasBrodala Thank you very much, I have added the stack trace

Comment: Can you update TYPO3 console to the latest version? See https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/releases/tag/v5.8.6

Comment: Great, I've re-added this as proper answer, can you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue and fixed with [version 5.8.6 of the TYPO3 Console](https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/releases/tag/v5.8.6).